# Javascript refresh query database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the website:
[enter link description here](http://yourkidsapest.com/)

Right now this is the function:

```
$("a.wtf").click(function(){
//get the id
the_id = $(this).attr('id');

// show the spinner
$(this).parent().html("<img src='images/thanks.fw.png'/>");

//the main ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "action=wtf&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
        url: "votes.php",
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut();
            $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
            $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();
            $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the rest:

```
<a href='javascript:;' class='wtf' id='".$list['id']."'>
```

Rephrased:
Right now, it displays an image after a user VOTES "WTF".
How would I replace the Vote link with new text displaying the new value of the WTF vote (probably a result of the query)

Comment: Will you bother to rephrase your question

Comment: sure, done. Sorry man.  I'm a moron.

Comment: your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Once you send the votes.php, hope you are update or insert the new vote, if is happenings like what  i mention in this means , you also fetch the newly inserted or updated values from db then return to the callback function

Example :

---

```
    $total_votes=100;
    $reuslut=$total."-".'Thanks for vote';
    echo $result;
    exit;

 in call back function :
 ---------------------

    success: function(msg)
    {
       var value=msg.split("-");
        $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut();
        $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(value[1]);
        $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();
        $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).remove();
        $(selector).html(value[1]);
    }
```

Hope it will help you for your question